# Load plugin for IKFast class using C++

Tags: ros, c++, ikfast, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am trying to load the IKFast MoveIt! plugin I already created through a C++ file using [pluginlib](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib). I am trying to do so in order to get access to the IKFast functions outside of MoveIt!.

When following the tutorial, I get this error when trying to compile using `catkin_make`:

```
Linking CXX executable /home/josh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ikfast_lf_plugin_load_test/IKFast_leg_LF_loader

CMakeFiles/IKFast_leg_LF_loader.dir/src/IKFast_leg_LF_loader.cpp.o: In function `std::map<std::string, class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase*>
> >& class_loader::class_loader_private::getFactoryMapForBaseClass<kinematics::KinematicsBase>()':

IKFast_leg_LF_loader.cpp:(.text._ZN12class_loader20class_loader_private25getFactoryMapForBaseClassIN10kinematics14KinematicsBaseEEERSt3mapISsPNS0_22AbstractMetaObjectBaseESt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsS6_EEEv[_ZN12class_loader20class_loader_private25getFactoryMapForBaseClassIN10kinematics14KinematicsBaseEEERSt3mapISsPNS0_22AbstractMetaObjectBaseESt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsS6_EEEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `typeinfo for kinematics::KinematicsBase'

CMakeFiles/IKFast_leg_LF_loader.dir/src/IKFast_leg_LF_loader.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTIPN10kinematics14KinematicsBaseE[_ZTIPN10kinematics14KinematicsBaseE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for kinematics::KinematicsBase'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [/home/josh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ikfast_lf_plugin_load_test/IKFast_leg_LF_loader] Error 1

make[1]: *** [ikfast_lf_plugin_load_test/CMakeFiles/IKFast_leg_LF_loader.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

Here is my code I am using:

```
#include <pluginlib/class_loader.h>
#include "/opt/ros/jade/include/moveit/kinematics_base/kinematics_base.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Create a classloader that is used to load the plugin
  pluginlib::ClassLoader<kinematics::KinematicsBase> poly_loader("moveit_core", "kinematics::KinematicsBase");

  try
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<kinematics::KinematicsBase> IKFast_LF = poly_loader.createInstance("ikfast_kinematics_plugin::IKFastKinematicsPluginLF");
    ROS_INFO("The plugin was loaded.");
  }
  catch(pluginlib::PluginlibException& ex)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("The plugin failed to load for some reason. Error: %s", ex.what());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have also copied the functions from the auto-generated `ikfast_moveit_plugin.cpp` into a header file, that would take the place of `polygon_plugins.h` in the tutorial. Also from the tutorial, `polygon_base.h`is replaced with `kinematics_base.h` from `/opt/ros/jade/include/moveit/kinematics_base/kinematics_base.h`.

Has anyone else come across this problem when trying to load a plugin?

Any help would be appreciated.

[Link to catkin package](https://github.com/JoshMarino/ikfast_plugin_load_test)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248266/load-plugin-for-ikfast-class-using-c++/) by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 592 on 2016-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The undefined reference error suggests there is a problem with linking. You are including the correct header but you are not linking it.

If you change the following in your CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pluginlib
  roscpp
  moveit_core
)
```

and change the header to include

```
#include <moveit/kinematics_base/kinematics_base.h>
```

you should be all set. Changing the include ensures that your system will be able to find the right header, even if the location might move (or should you use another ros distro).

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1